# Using PasteSpecial to Paste Values from a Function, and then Using that Range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to copy a range containing a function, such as

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($J$3:$J$702,$M3,COLUMNS($B4:$B4)),"")
```

and using pastespecial to paste the unformatted values resulting from this function in the adjacent column? Is there a timing issue with running this function in the sheet vs. running VBA? I've studied a number of threads out there regarding pastespecial, but I am unable to get this to work on my particular dataset. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Background Info:**

- I have a list of jokes in col J and their categories or genres in col I.
- Helper cols (K, L, M) exist to set up a filter and randomize the jokes.
- A data validation listbox containing the joke genres is in E3. Users will select a joke genre.
- Selecting a joke genre from E3 triggers an indexing of the genres starting in B3,

  =IFERROR(INDEX($I$3:$I$702,$M3,COLUMNS($A4:$A4)),"")

and associated jokes starting in C3,

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($J$3:$J$702,$M3,COLUMNS($B4:$B4)),"")
```

**The Problem:**
On the ListBox_Change, I'm trying to copy the range c4:c200 and use pastespecial to paste only the values into the adjacent d4:d200.
I'm doing all of this in order to extract one random joke from col D to display up in E1 (there's probably a much better way of doing this without this extra step, but I'm not much of a programmer...). Any help on correcting the code below, or suggesting an alternative way to simply show a random joke from either col C or D would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks.

```
Private Sub ListBox_Change()
    
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet: Set wsTarget = Worksheets("Jokes")
    Dim wsTargetRange As Range: Set wsTargetRange = wsTarget.Range("$E$3")
    
    If wsTargetRange.Address(True, True) = "$E$3" Then
        Select Case wsTargetRange
            Case "art"
                Call Generate
            Case "birthday"
                Call Generate
            Case "Computer"
                Call Generate
            Case "English"
                Call Generate
            Case "general"
                Call Generate
            Case "library"
                Call Generate
            Case "math"
                Call Generate
            Case "music"
                Call Generate
            Case "PE/sports"
                Call Generate
            Case "science"
                Call Generate
            Case "SS/history"
                Call Generate
            Case "winter"
                Call Generate
            Case Else
                'Do nothing
        End Select
    End If
End Sub

Sub Generate()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, i As Long, v
    Set ws = Sheets("Jokes")
    
    Set rng = ws.Range("C4:C200")
    rng.Select
    With Selection
        .Copy
    End With
    DoEvents 'I'm not sure about this.
    
    ws.Range("D4:D200").PasteSpecial
    '    DoEvents
    
    Set rng = ws.Range("D4:D200")
    Do 'trying to omit any blank cells
        i = Application.RandBetween(1, rng.Cells.Count)
        v = rng.Cells(i).Value
    Loop While Len(v) = 0  'loop until cell has a value
    
    ws.Range("E1").Value = v
    Set rng = ws.Range("E1")
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
End Sub
```

Comment: No need for `Select` or `Selection`. You can directly do `rng.Copy`. But actually, I suggest not using `Copy` and `PasteSpecial`. If you just want to take the values of some cells and put them in other cells, just do `ws.Range("D4:D200").Value = rng.Value`

Comment: To get a random number between 4 and 200, you can use the Excel function `RANDBETWEEN`. As you hypothesized, you don't need to copy values from "C" to "D" at all, and you could just select a random row from C4:C200 to copy into E1. `ws.Range("E1").Value = ws.Range("C" & Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(4, 200)).Value`

Comment: Thanks Toddleson for responding. Quick question. I'm just getting a blank cell in E1. But, for most of the joke genres, I don't have 200 jokes. Therefore, in essence, there are many blank rows in in the C4:C200 range, but I currently have the INDEX function in every row. Instead of specifying 4, 200, I'm thinking need to account for less than 196 jokes...

Comment: You could repeatedly draw values at random from 4 to 200 until a non-blank value is found. `While Len(Joke) = 0: Joke = ws.Range("C" & Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(4, 200)).Value: Wend`. Or you could sort the list to remove the blanks, either in Excel, or in a VBA array, and then your random search will be guaranteed to grab a non-blank value.

Comment: To quickly eliminate blanks, you can check the values before taking them from the worksheet. For example: `Dim JokeList As New Collection: Dim Joke As Variant: For Each Joke In Range("C4:C200").Value: If Len(CStr(Joke)) > 0 Then JokeList.Add CStr(Joke): Next`. Then you can just randomly grab a joke from the `JokeList` collection like `JokeList(WorksheetFunction.RANDBETWEEN(1,JokeList.Count))`

Comment: Thanks Toddleson. I'm trying what all you mentioned, but a random joke is not populating E1. To troubleshoot, I changed the range from C200 to C10 just to check, and E1 is still blank. Here is my code: Sub Generate(): Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, i As Long, v: Set ws = Sheets("Jokes"): Set rng = ws.Range("C4:C10"): Dim JokeList As New Collection: Dim Joke As Variant: For Each Joke In Range("C4:C10").Value: If Len(CStr(Joke)) > 0 Then: JokeList.Add CStr(Joke): End If: Next: ws.Range("E1").Value = JokeList(WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, JokeList.Count))

Comment: That code looks fine. Its hard to tell if the syntax is good when its written in the comments, but the actual statements themselves run when I put it into a new workbook.  Seems like there might be other troubles with the project. Also, with `Set ws = Sheets(...` you should include the parent workbook, otherwise it defaults to `ActiveWorkbook`. For example `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(...` or `Set ws = Workbooks("Jokes.xlsx").Sheets(...`

Comment: Oh I just saw, `For Each Joke In Range("C4:C10").Value` you should add the parent worksheet for that range, `For Each Joke In ws.Range("C4:C10").Value`

Comment: Thanks for your time and code examples Toddleson. I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given jokes en genres starting at row 4, I've filled a listbox with a sub

```
Sub fillList()
    Dim arr, i As Long, lRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Jokes")
    lRow = ws.Range("I" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    arr = ws.Range("I3:I" & lRow).Value2 'the list of genres (not filtered)
    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        If Not dict.Exists(arr(i, 1)) Then 'getting the unique values with a dictionary
            dict.Add arr(i, 1), ""
        End If
    Next i
    ListBox1.List = dict.Keys 'filling the list with the unique values
    Set dict = Nothing
End Sub
```

You could technically call this with a button or in Workbook_Open if you'd like to update the list when more jokes are added.
Next we continue with the user selecting a different genre:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
    Debug.Print "Listbox changed: " & ListBox1.Text
    Dim amtJokes As Long, lRow As Long, joke As String
    Dim arr, arrFilter, ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
    
    joke = ListBox1.Text
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Jokes")
    lRow = ws.Range("I" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = ws.Range("I3:I" & lRow)
    arr = rng.Resize(, 2).Value2
    amtJokes = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, joke) 'count the amount of jokes to give a clear boundry to the arrFilter
    ReDim arrFilter(1 To amtJokes, 1 To 1)
    Dim i As Long, cnt As Long
    cnt = 1
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1) 'go through the entire list and keep only the good ones
        If arr(i, 1) = joke Then
            arrFilter(cnt, 1) = arr(i, 2)
            cnt = cnt + 1
        End If
    Next i
    
    Dim rnd As Long
    rnd = Application.RandBetween(1, UBound(arrFilter, 1)) 'get a random position in the array
    Range("E1").Value = arrFilter(rnd, 1) 'give the user a (good) chuckle or loud exhale through the nose
    
End Sub
```

This evades whatever was going on in columns C/D/K/L/M (sorry if this wasn't meant to be)
Let me know if something isn't clear.

Comment: Thanks so much Notus_Panda for responding. So, I'm not very experienced with Excel VBA. When you coded ListBox1, were you thinking on inserting a form listbox control or an ActiveX listbox control? I currently had a listbox made from data validation. I've not dealt with the controls in a spreadsheet environment. Just curious...

Comment: This was done with a ActiveX listbox control, that's why I added the fill listbox sub. I'll have to take a look as to what needs to change for your specific listbox case, I'm not familiar with that one.

Comment: I've checked out your "listbox" from data validation but this is just a dropdown list, it's not the same as an actual listbox to have code behind it, afaik you're also dealing with multiple values in your dropdown list?. You could still get your joke if you want to stay with that but then you'd have to go with the `Worksheet_Change` event and check if E3 is changed and then adjust my code with `joke = ws.Range("E3")` (put the joke rule below the `Set ws = ...`).

Comment: Hi Notus_Panda. Thanks for this extra info. I added an activeX listbox. However, I am getting an error: Subscript out of Range, pertaining to ReDim arrFilter(1 To amtJokes, 1 To 1). The col with all of the typed jokes is col J, and the col with their corresponding genres is col I. Users select the genre of joke in col I with a data validation listbox. Both cols I and J have a header in row in row 2 - the genres and jokes start in row 3 and extend down. Col K was only used as a helper col in my initial attempt at filtering/indexing.

Comment: Edited my answer to accommodate the correct columns, my bad ^^

Comment: That's a really cool solution. I'll have to study and learn about it more. I've never dealt with CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary"). It works great. Thanks for your time Notus_Panda.

Comment: You're welcome, Dictionaries are very handy when needing to deal with unique values and [late binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/early-late-binding/) is just easier to deal with if other users are involved.